# Django-rest-framework: Authentication/permissions error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn about django-rest-framework and I am stuck in the authentication/permissions processes. I hope someone could help me. Below is my code:

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'drones.custompagination.LimitOffsetPaginationWithUpperBound',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 4,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

**models.py**

```
class Drone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                            unique=True)
    drone_category = models.ForeignKey(DroneCategory,
                                       related_name='drones',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturing_date = models.DateTimeField()
    has_it_competed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='drones',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class DroneList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Drone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DroneSerializer
    name = 'drone-list'
    permission_classes = (
        'permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
        'custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly',
    )
    filterset_fields = (
        'name',
        'drone_category',
        'manufacturing_date',
        'has_it_competed',
    )
    search_fileds = (
        'name',
    )
    ordering_fields = (
        'name',
        'manufacturing_date',
    )
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class DroneDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Drone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DroneSerializer
    name = 'drone-detail'
    permission_classes = (
        'permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
        'custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly',
    )
```

**custompermission.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            # The method is a safe method
            return True
        else:
            # The method is not a safe method
            # Only owners are granted permissions
            return obj.owner == request.user
```

And and below is the error that django is throwing:

```
[03/Nov/2019 18:01:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10070
Internal Server Error: /drones/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 493, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 411, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 331, in check_permissions
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 278, in get_permissions
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
  File "/home/martin/python/learn_rest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 278, in <listcomp>
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
[03/Nov/2019 18:01:45] "GET /drones/ HTTP/1.1" 500 107476
```

- **Python version: 3.5.3**
- **Django version: 2.2.6**
- **Django Rest Framework version: 3.10.3**

*I have been searching here for other people having the same problem, but none of the solutions provided seem to work for this particular case*

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the value of `permission_classes` to the permission classes directly, something like:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
#import your custome permission module
class DroneDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Drone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DroneSerializer
    name = 'drone-detail'
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help :)